# Why, when creating new row in DB, currentValue in key is equal to this strange int?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've found this weird error.

I have my logging system which logs all changes in database.
I'm using this to get keys of edited or added values. Short explain:

```
var changes = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified || p.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();

foreach (var change in changes) {
    ...
    var primaryKeys = change.Properties.Where(key => key.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
        .ToDictionary(key => key.Metadata.Name,
           key => key.CurrentValue.ToString());;
    ...
}
```

And when some row is added and key is **int**, `key.CurrentValue` is always equal to `-2147482647`.
It's strange because **int** minimal is `-2147483648` so diffrence is `1001`.

Once again:

key.CurrentValue: -214748**2**64**7**

Int minimal: -214748**3**64**8**

Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Have you checked this closed issue? https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7743 and this https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10167

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks **Selva TS**!

This strange int is actually a temporary ID coded in Entity Framework. Since my ID is auto incremented in my DB, it isn't a problem for me.

They even have test for that so it isn't a bug, it's a feature :D

[Tests](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/search?l=C%23&q=int.MinValue+%2B1001&type=)